# Is there a function available in c# that would return 7 as the number of days that make up a week

Tags: c#, datetime

If I take Wednesday May 2 2017 as a start date and Tuesday 8 May as an end date and feed those as parameters to the following code;

```
TimeSpan duration =  startDate - endDate;
return Convert.ToDouble(duration.TotalDays);
```

I get 6 returned.  I understand the reason why but instinctively one would (or at least I would) look upon that period as being a week (or 7 days). Is there a readily available function in C# that would return 7 as the number of days that that date range represents?

Comment: What is the type of `startDate` and `endDate`? Is it `DateTime`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes both are defined as being of type Datetime

Comment: Try using this formula: `duration.Ticks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - TimeSpan.TicksPerHour*4)`. This should give you what you want. I will say though that `6` seems more of a natural answer than `7`. So be sure you really want this.

Comment: @Icemanind  the notion of the week comes from the fact that the end user has what they view as as weekly accounting period that runs from Wednesday to the following Tuesday.  Anything that happens in that period gets wrapped into that weeks accounts.  They view that as being 7 days and get 'confused' by anything that might suggest it's 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `DateTime` does not represent dates, it represents points in time that include dates. When you write "May-2, 2018", `DateTime` represents it as "Midnight of May-2, 2018". When you subtract `endDate` from `startDate`, you are computing the amount of time passed between midnights of May-2 and May-8, which is exactly 6.

Since you would like to include both ends into your computation, you need to add 1 day to the result:

```
var from = new DateTime(2018, 5, 2);
var to = new DateTime(2018, 5, 8);
var diff = to.Date - from.Date + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalDays); // Prints 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> get 6 returned. I understand the reason why but instinctively one would (or at least I would) look upon that period as being a week (or 7 days).

It says 6 days because it *is* 6 days.

If you specify startdate as "5/2/2018 00:00:00" and enddate as "5/8/2018 23:59:59", the answer is 6.23:59:59 days.

If you use 5/2 & 5/3, it returns 1, which is correct. This is no different than what it does with your test data.